# UICollectionView Spacing Not Equal

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a vertical `UICollectionView` with standard width and variable height cells. I have an issue with the spacing. For each height of a cell the spacing after the cell is different:

Screenshot of the UICollectionView

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An `UICollectionView` has the [`delegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618033-delegate) property. You should implement the [`UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout) in some class, for example the View Controller.

This methods are responsible for spacing:

```
// Space around the section.
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                   layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
                   insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)
}

// In case of vertical layout this is a vertical space between horizontal rows inside of each section
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
                    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20
}

// Horizontal space between items in row
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,  
                    minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20
}
```